# what could be the best method to find best scenario based on revenue(statistical analysis) in python?

Tags: regression, python

I have a data set on which I want to do some statistical analysis. The sample data set is in a `csv` file and of following nature:

```
Restaurant Type  City,         Capacity    Property category Average Occupancy Revenue
Siting,          San Fransisco 120 to 150  Stand Alone       70                311612
Self Service     San Fransisco 120 to 150  Mall              78                190000
Siting           San Jose      80 to 100   Mall              50                230000
Siting           San Fransisco 120 to 150  Stand Alone       85                280000
Self Service     San Jose      120 to 150  Mall              70                310000
```

One of the analyses I want to do is to find which type of Restaurant (Sitting or Self Service) is better based on revenues?

Another is what type of property category is beneficial based on revenues?

Yet another analysis could be what kind of Restaurant is better based on capacity, average occupancy and revenue?

I am new to statistical analysis, so I am having trouble to find a suitable algorithm to do such analyses? What could be some of the good algorithms to do the analyses?

NOTE: I know this question is subjective and open to debate but since I am new to this so I am having trouble. Apologies in advance!